# Loop Over Files as Input for Program, Rename and Write Output to Different Directory

Tags: for-loop, command-line

I have a problem with writing the output of a program to a different directory when I loop different files as variables as inputs. I run this in the command line. The problem is that I do not know how to "tell" the program to put the output with a changed filename into another directory than the input directory.

Here is the command, although it is a bioinformatic tool which requires specific input file formats. I am sorry that I could not give a better example. Nonetheless, the program is called computeMatrix in a software-tool box called deeptools2.

command:

```
for f in ~/my/path/*spc_files*; do computeMatrix reference-point--referencePoint center --regionsFileName /target/region.bed --binSize 500 --scoreFileName "$f" **--outFileName "$f.matrix"** ; done \
```

So far, I tried to use the command basename to just get the filename and then change the directory before that. However I could not figure out:

1. if this is combinable
2. what is the correct order of the commands (e.g.:

   outputFile='basename"$f"', "~/new/targetDir/'basename$f'")

Probably there are other options to solve the problem which I could not think of/ find.